# Error: getting error with "flutter run" with different flavors and target file

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I am trying to run one of my project with my other system in which my Flutter SDK was 3.16.8. Now, Then I have downgraded my SDK to 3.13.9 due to some specific reasons and when I have tried to run it with bellow command then I am getting error like:

Command:

> flutter run --flavor dev -t "lib/dev_main.dart"

Error:

> [+33149 ms] ProcessException: No such file or directory
> Command: /Users/usr/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/android/gradlew --full-stacktrace --info -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64
> -Ptarget=/Users/usr/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/lib/dev_main.dart
> -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application
> -Pdart-defines=RkxVVFRFUl9XAAAfQVVUT19ERAAAA1Q9dHJ1ZQ==,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQ0FOVkFTS0lUX1AAAA1odHRwczovL3d3dy5nc3RhdQljLmNvbS9mbWW0dGVyLWNhbnZhc2tpdC8wCCC1Zjg3MDVkZjMwMTg3N2Q3ODcxMDdiYWMxBBBlOWZjOWVlMWFkLw==
> -Pdart-obfuscation=false
> -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDevDebug

Stack trace:

> [   +7 ms]
> #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
> #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:760:9)
>
> #2      FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1297:27)
>
> #3      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
>
> #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:339:9)
>
> #6      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:285:5)
>
> #8      run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:115:9)
>
> #9      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)

All the things which I have tried are mentioned bellow:

1. Clean and rebuild Project
2. Restart and Reimport project
3. reconfigure and redownload flutter SDK with version 3.13.9.
4. Searched on Stack-overflow and ChatGPT.
5. Tried to reconfigure it path in .zprofile(for mac).
6. Reconfigure android studio.

Comment: it just without quotes.  flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/dev_main.dart

Answer (score 0):

The correct way should be this and **main_dev is my project file**.

```
flutter run --target=lib/main_dev.dart --flavor dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your instant response Ankit, I have used you provided cmd and I am still facing same issue.

Comment: What issue are you getting